# Sage's (or Maxima's) solve gives a bad answer for diff(p, x) == 0?

Tags: sage, maxima

I am using Sage to (within a script) solve a simple equation in two variables:

```
sage: x, y = var("x y")
sage: p = x*y + x/y + 1/x
sage: diff(p, x)
y + 1/y - 1/x^2
sage: diff(p, y)
x - x/y^2
sage: solve([diff(p,x)==0, diff(p,y)==0], [x,y])
[[x == 0, y == 0], [x == -1/2*sqrt(2), y == 1],
 [x == 1/2*sqrt(2), y == 1], [x == -1/2*I*sqrt(2), y == -1],
 [x == 1/2*I*sqrt(2), y == -1]]
```

For some reason, Sage returns a solution that isn't a solution at all, here [x == 0, y == 0] can easily be seen **NOT** to be an answer of [y + 1/y - 1/x^2 == 0, x - x/y^2 == 0].

Is this a bug? a known bug? or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**: rephrased the title, and I am wondering, worst case, how can I substitute the solutions back in the system to manually check if the equations are verified?

PS: I would post this on AskSage, but it is currently down.

Comment: Rephrase the title/question *without* supposing a "bug". Simply state the issue and observed/expected behaviors.

Comment: how does sage usually define the derivative at a discontinuous point? obviously those functions are *not* the derivative at x == 0, y == 0 since there is no derivative there, so sage isn't solving them, but rather solving whatever it interprets the derivative to be - possibly it is considered zero at undefined points, rather than considered undefined. (i am not at all familiar with sage)

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like Maxima's `solve` function is returning the spurious solution [x = 0, y = 0]. I see that Maxima's `to_poly_solve` is better behaved here.

```
p : x*y + x/y + 1/x;
load (to_poly_solve);
[dpx, dpy] : [diff (p, x), diff (p, y)];
to_poly_solve ([dpx, dpy], [x, y]);
  => %union([x = -1/sqrt(2),y = 1],[x = 1/sqrt(2),y = 1],
         [x = -%i/sqrt(2),y = -1],[x = %i/sqrt(2),y = -1])

for xy in args (%) do print (subst (xy, [dpx, dpy]));
  =>
   [0,0] 
   [0,0] 
   [0,0] 
   [0,0]
```

I don't know how to call `to_poly_solve` from Sage, although I'm pretty sure it's possible.

Hope this helps. Good luck & have fun.

Comment: In principle, `solve([y + 1/y - 1/x^2==0,x - x/y^2==0],[x,y],to_poly_solve='force')` should avoid the Maxima `solve` command and only use `to_poly_solve`, but I still get the spurious extra output there as well because that only is true for single equations, not systems.  I've opened http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15859 for this.

Comment: Of course, the OP or Robert can also open a Maxima bug report for this.